# Q: Where can I find OneNote 2013 C/C++ header files?

Tags: office-2013, onenote, onenote-api

I've searched the web, and can only find references to older version header files, such as [Office 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2007/02/06/creating-a-c-c-add-in-which-works-with-onenote.aspx) and [Office 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2011/08/24/c-c-add-ins-for-onenote-2010.aspx).  Are there header files for Office 2013?

Comment: @Lightness, I mean the C programming language -OR- C++ programming language.

Comment: Why not specify which one you're actually using? Wouldn't that be more helpful?

Comment: Because to me, it doesn't matter which one.  I can work in either language.

Comment: Well, ignoring for a moment that you're likely not considering various idiomatic differences that make the choice really quite an important one, for the purposes of questions on Stack Overflow, you are to have chosen a language before asking. Otherwise the question is too broad. This particular question is off-topic anyway. Good luck!

Comment: How is this question off-topic when I have tagged it specifically to both languages and also to Office 2013?  I don't see the point of asking the same question twice in two places, but with a specific tag to each question.  Are you a moderator?  I'm not trying to be confrontational, I'm just trying to understand the rules because it seems silly.

Comment: It is off-topic because you are asking us for off-site resources. It is irrelevant whether I am a moderator or not: this site is run by the community, and you did not read [the topic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting (which go way beyond tagging). And, no, it's not "silly". Good luck!

Comment: @Lightness, I was asking for a pointer to any online reference only (if it exists), not for any resources to be handed to me or packaged for me.  But thanks for contributing to the community and adhering to the rules.  I'll continue to search elsewhere for help.

Comment: Right, and (one last time) that's _off-topic_, per the rules I just linked you to.